# How to forward traffic to an on-premise Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, load-balancing, network-traffic, metallb

I'm trying to understand how traffic can be forwarded to an on-premise Kubernetes cluster.

It's clear to me that in a public Cloud provider, the underlying infrastructure of the Cloud can automatically manage and forward traffic to a Kubernetes distribution, such as EKS, GKE, AKS, by assining a `LoadBalancer` IP to a Kubernetes `Service`. Then, after a few seconds, this service will receive an external IP and will be reachable from the outside world.

On the other hand, in an on-premise Kubernetes cluster, by assigning a `LoadBalancer` IP to a service, it stays on pending forever, unless you assign a node IP, but what if you want to assign a different IP from a private IP range? In order to tackle this, in my homelab, I've deployed `metallb` inside my K3s cluster. The `metallb` is configured to use a private IP range of my network, let's say `10.0.0.0/24`. Now, services of type `LoadBalancer` can consume an address of this range, e.g. my Ingress Controller can receive `10.0.2.3` as its external IP.

I can't understand what's `metallb` doing under the hood. How `metallb` "listens" to an address of the range and forwards traffic to my cluster. Can this be achieved without a `metallb`? I've tried setting an `ExternalIP` directly to a service of type `LoadBalancer`, but it never managed to claim that specific IP without it.

In addition, I'm aware that this can also be achieved with a "physical" load-balancer solution, such as NGINX and HAProxy, that sits in front of the cluster. To my understanding, technically this does the same thing as `metallb`. With such a solution configured, an address can be listened and be forwarded to the cluster. But my question here is, can this be achieved without those technologies? Can a Kubernetes Cluster listen to an external address and accept traffic without an intermediate solution? Maybe through Firewall rules and port-forwarding?

Your time is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This involves some of the core networking concepts like NATing, you can have two networks one local and one external CIDR. For exposing the services you can NAT the local CIDR with external CIDR and configure required firewall rules for making your cluster serve the public.

Comment: @Sovenique is your issue resolved, revert back if you need any additional help. Upvote or accept this solution so that it can be helpful for remaining community members.